# Rails form validation: how to properly display the error for a checkbox

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, checkbox

From what I can tell, my question should be pretty easy to answer for someone who encountered this issue before ...

I have a signup form in rails which should highlight the fields that are not properly completed when the submit button is clicked (it should also show relevant error messages). The form contains only input fields and a checkbox. While the errors are properly displayed for each part of the form, the checkbox label is not properly highlighted in red when the user tries to submit the form whithout checking the checkbox.

What should I modify in my code to have the checkbox label highlighted when the checkbox is left unchecked?

This is the view code:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <br>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
  <label_for="user_terms_of_service">I agree to the <%= link_to "Terms of Service", policies_path %>
  </label>
  <br><br>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Also, this is what I can see with Firebug for the checkbox after the form is improperly submitted - the problem is that the div with class="field_with_errors" is put before the checkbox label.

```
<br>
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[terms_of_service]">
<div class="field_with_errors">
<input id="user_terms_of_service" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[terms_of_service]">
</div>
<label_for="user_terms_of_service">
```

Thank you for your help,
Alexandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label syntax is not correct.  Try

```
<%= f.label :user_terms_of_service, "I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path}.".html_safe %>
```

Comment: If I use your first suggestion, I get this as the checkbox label: `I agree to the <a href="/policies">Terms of Service</a>.`. This is something that I previously tried, actually. Do you know how to allow the link to properly appear? For the second suggestion I got errors. After removing the equal sign for the if, else, end lines, there was a problem about `errors` not being recognized.

Comment: What are you thinking is the correct label?  This looks okay to me.

Comment: The text above is what is visible on the page, not in the source code. I would like to see "I agree to the Terms of Service", where Terms of Service can be clicked on.

Comment: Ah!  Try adding `.html_safe` to the parameter string as I did in the post.  (To the first suggestion.)

Comment: ALso the reason mention of the errors hash gave errors is that it's actually an attribute of the model object where the error is set.  I put this in the post as well.

Comment: No need for html_safe, simply use a block with label:
   ```<%= f.label(: user_terms_of_service) do %>
      I accept <%= link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path %>
   <% end %>```

Answer (score 2):

My approach with forms is to try and use the rails standards where possible, e.g.

Add to your User model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms
attr_accessible :terms
```

In your view,

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.check_box :terms %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You actually don't need an extra column in the users table unless you want to grant access to users who have not accepted the terms of service, which... don't exist as they can't complete registrations in the first place.